# I want club of this two query with all the information

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select r.resource_id,r.resort_id,r.parent_id,r.type,r.code,r.name,r.implicationmanager_id, 
    i.implies_id,i.valid_from,i.valid_to,i.BOOK_FROM,i.BOOK_TO 
from resourcebasei18n r 
join implies i on r.IMPLICATIONMANAGER_ID=i.IMPLICATIONMANAGER_ID;

select i.implies_id,i.valid_from,i.valid_to,i.BOOK_FROM,i.BOOK_TO,
    d.resource_id as implied_resource_id,
    r.resort_id,r.parent_id,r.type,
    r.code as implied_resource_code,
    r.name as implied_resource_name 
from implies i
join implied d on i.implies_id=d.implies_id
join resourcebasei18n r on d.resource_id=r.resource_id;
```

Comment: What do you mean by club? UNION of all the rows (which will be hard as they are different data) or join between the two giving you all the columns, in which case you will need to specify how to join the two.

Comment: I want join of these two queries but the problem is resource id of second query is implied resource id while the resource id of first query is simple resource id 
for example if a hotel room is product then its resource id is 1 and a bed is another product then its resource id 2 but when bed is implied on hotel room simple resource id turns to implied resource id .

Comment: Is it possible to share some sample data

Comment: I cant see any difficulty here. If you understand the schema, where is the problem with the join? You already appear to be joining between all the right tables in the second query. I edited the query to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need this -

```
SELECT i.implies_id
      ,i.valid_from
      ,i.valid_to
      ,i.BOOK_FROM
      ,i.BOOK_TO
      ,d.resource_id as implied_resource_id
      ,r.resort_id
      ,r.parent_id
      ,r.type
      ,r.code as implied_resource_code
      ,r.name as implied_resource_name
      ,r.resource_id
      ,r.name
      ,r.implicationmanager_id
FROM implies i
JOIN implied d ON i.implies_id=d.implies_id
JOIN resourcebasei18n r ON d.resource_id=r.resource_id
                        AND r.IMPLICATIONMANAGER_ID=i.IMPLICATIONMANAGER_ID;
```

If you need anything other than this, Please post some sample data and expected result.